# Qt non-blocking overlay dialog

Tags: c++, qt, dialog, modal-dialog

I would like to make a dialog in Qt 4.8 that is non-blocking to the parent dialog but stays on top of it while open.

What I tried so far:

## Parent

The following code does exactly what I want on Gnome but on Windows/Mac the dialog goes to the back when the main window gains the focus:

```
QMainWindow* window = new QMainWindow();
QDialog* dialog = new QDialog( window );

window->show();
dialog->show();
```

## Always on top

There is also the possibility to make the dialog always on top but I don't think that my application will be so incredibly important to the user that he wants it to even be on top of other applications:

```
dialog->setWindowFlags( dialog->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint );
```

## Modal dialog

There is also the possibility to make a window modal dialog. But that blocks user interaction with the main window while the dialog is open.

```
dialog->setWindowModality( Qt::WindowModal );
```

## Dock widget

A dock widget does pretty much what it should. But it also docks and does not look like a dialog.

What am I looking for?

Comment: Are you sure? I've not tried on Mac, but on Windows I've always done as your code and the dialog stays on top of the window

Comment: I only have a running application (with a lot of additional code with possible side effects) tested on Windows and no Windows system available right now. But for sure it does not work on mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is modalless tool window.

```
QMainWindow* window = new QMainWindow();
QDialog* dialog = new QDialog( window );

Qt::WindowFlags flags = dialog->windowFlags();
dialog->setWindowFlags(flags | Qt::Tool);

window->show();
dialog->show();
```

Excerpted from QT document, this is meaning of Qt::Tool flag:

*Indicates that the widget is a tool window. A tool window is often a small window with a smaller than usual title bar and decoration, typically used for collections of tool buttons. If there is a parent, the tool window will always be kept on top of it. If there isn't a parent, you may consider using Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint as well. If the window system supports it, a tool window can be decorated with a somewhat lighter frame. It can also be combined with Qt::FramelessWindowHint. On OS X, tool windows correspond to the Floating class of windows. This means that the window lives on a level above normal windows; it impossible to put a normal window on top of it. By default, tool windows will disappear when the application is inactive. This can be controlled by the Qt::WA_MacAlwaysShowToolWindow attribute.*

Comment: Thanks, really nice. However, the window will disappear when the application is inactive (like documented). Unfortunately `Qt::WA_MacAlwaysShowToolWindow` does the same as `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` on mac. You wouldn't have an idea how to change make it stay on top of only this application when it lost the focus?

Comment: Mac indeed has a bug, please check out https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-29816

Comment: Thanks again. Seems to be solved with Qt 5.8 https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45938

Comment: how to show a dialog blocks only some windows rather than the entire application?